# PSQL server, 'relation does not exist' when sending a request through Postman

Tags: javascript, postgresql, postman, psql

I have a very basic sql file, the code:

```
\c postgres
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS project1;
CREATE DATABASE project1;
\c parky

CREATE TABLE works (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    workshop TEXT NOT NULL,
    attendee TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

this is used by my Javascript server:

```
require('dotenv').config()
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.set("port", 8080);

app.use(bodyParser.json({ type: "application/json" }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const Pool = require("pg").Pool;
const config = {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: "project1"
};
const pool = new Pool(config);

//Add an attendee to workshop
app.post("/api", async (req, res) => {
  const ws = req.body.workshop;
  const att = req.body.attendee;

  try{
    const template = "SELECT * from works WHERE workshop = $1 AND attendee = $2";
     console.log("in the select statement");
    const response = await pool.query(template, [ws, att]);
   
    //if attendee and workshop already exists
    if(response.rowCount != 0){
        res.json({status: "attendee already enrolled"});
    
    } else if (response.rowCount ==0){
    //else if attendee and workshop doesn't exist
    //INSERT the entry
        const template2 = "INSERT INTO works(workshop, attendee) VALUES ($1, $2)";
        console.log("in the insert statement");
        const response1 = await pool.query(template2,  [ws, att]);
    res.json({status: "added"});
    }
    
    }catch (err){
        console.log("Error.")
        console.log(err);
    }
    })
app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
  console.log(`Find the server at: http://localhost:${app.get("port")}/`); 
});
```

The keys passed though Postman are:

```
workshop  : React Fundamentals
attendee  : Claire Kim
```

But every time I try to insert these values into the table, I get this error:

```
error: relation "works" does not exist
```

Referring to the line:

```
    const template = "SELECT * from works WHERE workshop = $1 AND attendee = $2";
     console.log("in the select statement");
    const response = await pool.query(template, [ws, att]);
```

But in PSQL, when I enter the select statement, it works fine and the table "works" is there. My user 'parky' has permissions to select and insert to "works" and also usage to select on sequence to the works_id_seq table.

I've been working on this for 6 hours but have no idea what's going wrong. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible issues: 1) Not connecting to correct instance of database. Check database log for connection  2) `search_path` issue. Try schema qualifying the table name.

Comment: If my guess is not wrong then please verify that multiple version of PostgreSQL should not install, because if multiple version exists, and might they run on a different port such as 5433, 5434.

Else you should check the port number of PostgreSQL currently running on your machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's the actual SQL file you used to create your table, then you created the table in the database named parky.

The output of `\c parky` should say something like this:

`You are now connected to database "parky" as user "postgres"`

That line should probably be something like:
`\c project1 parky`

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Thank you so much. I was so frustrated